# RPI registers often at router

Tags: ethernet

For some reason, my RPI registers many local ip addresses at the router. It is connected by ethernet cable, and doesn't reboot in the meantime. 
I can't find anything about online...

Here's a screenshot from the router admin:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure these are not historical values?

Answer (score 2):

Check the TTL of the DHCP leases. if it's too low, your RPi may be requesting a new IP in a very short basis.

I had a similar issue long time ago because the router was a faulty unit. Check with another DHCP server.

Anyway, to find out when your RPi is requesting a new IP, I'd set a logging script so it logs the IPs to a file every hour. If it changes in less than an hour, I'd low the running basis.

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> /root/IP.log
ifconfig eth0 | grep addr >> /root/IP.log
echo '==============================='
```

set it on crontab to run in your desire basis.

Attention: It doesn't even need to be run as root!!

Comment: Ok I'm going to give that a try!

Comment: this code does not log when your RPi is requesting a new IP address, is logs the at runtime assigned IP address (which may be usefull as well)

Comment: Yes, the idea is running a simple script which let you track if your Rpi is changing it IP and for how long it keeps the one it recieves. As this is an easy task is not worth developing nothing more elaborated (IMHO)